# When using "yield" why does compiler-generated type implement both IEnumerable and IEnumerator

Tags: c#, .net, linq, garbage-collection, yield-return

We are trying to use an `IEnumerable` as a factory that generates different objects each time we iterate over it. Those should be GC'ed as soon as possible. Note however that we **keep a reference to the enumerator** so we can call it again.  So our program basically looks like this:

```
public class YieldSpec
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> Strings()
    {
        yield return "AAA";
        yield return "BBB";
        yield return "CCC";
    } 
    public void YieldShouldAllowGC()
    {
        var e = Strings();
        foreach (var a in e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a);
        }

    }
}
```

Looking at that code in the debugger:

[image]

You can see that when the breakpoint is hit the IEnumerable has a reference to **"CCC"**.

This shouldn't really happen. IEnumerable should only generate an IEnumerator when GetEnumerator is called. Is this expected behavior that IEnumerable can contain state?

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Sure you disposed all instances? Using [this code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M4AdN8).

Comment: Did you get rid of the instance to `Test`? It doesn't dispose the entire thing until you disposed `Test`. (it is lazy)

Comment: AFAIK the scope leaving `Test()` (or more specifically, after the `foreach()` already) will make the enumerator eligible for garbage collection. What is the problem? That _directly_ after calling `Test()`, GC didn't yet kick in?

Comment: The problem is that we hold a reference to the IEnumerable. We don't expect the IEnumerable to hold state. The IEnumerator should hold state. However the IEnumerable holds a reference to the IEnumerator. This prevents GC of the IEnumerator and last object it refers to.

Comment: Please actually paste your code into the question instead of a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry about that but I wanted to show the output of the watch and the fact that I had a breakpoint. Added the pastable code as well

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As an implementation detail for performance reasons, yes, the state machine implements both `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator`.  That said, it is smart enough to do this correctly.  It is only the very first time that the `IEnumerable` is asked for an `IEnumerator` that it returns itself.  Any future calls to `GetEnumerator` result in a new instance of the object being created, so that the separate iterator states can be maintained.  This is done because while it is important to be *able* to have an `IEnumerable` create multiple `IEnumerators`, the *vast* majority of actual situations involve exactly one being created, so that's the situation that was optimized for.

Comment: That clarifies some confusion I saw when running the debugger. I ran the IEnumerable multiple times but only saw the __Current__ property being updated on the first run. This makes it all clear.

Comment: @bradgonesurfing: To clarify this correct answer, the "performance reason" here is *to lower GC pressure*. You can easily imagine a situation where these methods that contain `yield`s are called thousands of times a second and immediately enumerated. If we can decrease by half the number of new objects created when that happens, it's a clear win.

Comment: Hi @EricLippert I completely understand the reasoning and it seems a perfect tradeoff. It just tripped me up because I found a whole load of objects through profiling that I assumed should have been GC'd. In my case it's the root node of a large heirarchy of WPF context menus. I'd prefer they do get GC'd instead of being held by the IEnumerable. My case is an outlier and I'll find a way around it.